# Errors while importing oracle database update with impdp command

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, impdp

I am facing a strange errors(ORA-31693, ORA-31645, ORA-19501, ORA-27070, OSD-04016) while importing the oracle database update though impdp command.

Below is error log please assist me resolving this error

```
    ;;; 
Import: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Fri Nov 2 10:56:03 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

. . imported "ACSELE_BRHN"."COBERTURAS"                  12.51 GB 11916056 rows
ORA-31693: Table data object "ACSELE_BRHN"."THIRDPARTYMOVEMENTRISKUNIT" failed to load/unload and is being skipped due to error:
ORA-31645: unable to read from dump file "D:\app\OracleHomeUser1\admin\orcl\dpdump\/739D4E707E75409582A9155D63EFDF44\Backup05-10-2018-Pre_ProdWi.dmp"
ORA-19501: read error on file "D:\app\OracleHomeUser1\admin\orcl\dpdump\/739D4E707E75409582A9155D63EFDF44\Backup05-10-2018-Pre_ProdWi.dmp", block number 4720640 (block size=4096)
ORA-27070: async read/write failed
OSD-04016: Error queuing an asynchronous I/O request.
O/S-Error: (OS 1117) The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.
. . imported "ACSELE_BRHN"."STPO_POLICYASLPHYSICAL"      1.548 GB  811657 rows
. . imported "ACSELE_BRHN"."OASALDOSDEUDORES"            1.131 GB 6014979 rows
ORA-39014: One or more workers have prematurely exited.
ORA-39029: worker 1 with process name "DW00" prematurely terminated
ORA-31671: Worker process DW00 had an unhandled exception.
ORA-31643: unable to close dump file "D:\app\OracleHomeUser1\admin\orcl\dpdump\/739D4E707E75409582A9155D63EFDF44\Backup05-10-2018-Pre_ProdWi.dmp"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPW$WORKER", line 2380
ORA-19501: read error on file "D:\app\OracleHomeUser1\admin\orcl\dpdump\/739D4E707E75409582A9155D63EFDF44\Backup05-10-2018-Pre_ProdWi.dmp", block number 5879680 (block size=4096)
ORA-27070: async read/write failed
OSD-04016: Error queuing an asynchronous I/O request.
O/S-Error: (OS 1117) The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.
ORA-19501: read error on file "D:\app\OracleHomeUser1\admin\orcl\dpdump\/739D4E707E75409582A9155D63EFDF44\Backup05-10-2018-Pre_ProdWi.dmp", block number 5879872 (block size=4096)
ORA-27070: async read/write failed
OSD-04016: Error queuing an asynchronous I/O request.
O/S-Error: (OS 1117) The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPD$DATA_INT", line 1386
ORA-06512: at line 2
ORA-39014: One or more workers have prematurely exited.
ORA-39029: worker 2 with process name "DW01" prematurely terminated
ORA-31671: Worker process DW01 had an unhandled exception.
ORA-31643: unable to close dump file "D:\app\OracleHomeUser1\admin\orcl\dpdump\/739D4E707E75409582A9155D63EFDF44\Backup05-10-2018-Pre_ProdWi.dmp"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPW$WORKER", line 2380

ORA-19501: read error on file "D:\app\OracleHomeUser1\admin\orcl\dpdump\/739D4E707E75409582A9155D63EFDF44\Backup05-10-2018-Pre_ProdWi.dmp", block number 5880000 (block size=4096)
ORA-27070: async read/write failed
OSD-04016: Error queuing an asynchronous I/O request.
O/S-Error: (OS 1117) The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.
ORA-19501: read error on file "D:\app\OracleHomeUser1\admin\orcl\dpdump\/739D4E707E75409582A9155D63EFDF44\Backup05-10-2018-Pre_ProdWi.dmp", block number 5879872 (block size=4096)
ORA-27070: async read/write failed
OSD-04016: Error queuing an asynchronous I/O request.
O/S-Error: (OS 1117) The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPD$DATA_INT", line 1386

Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_04" stopped due to fatal error at Fri Nov 2 11:32:02 2018 elapsed 0 00:35:47
```

Comment: How did you copy the dump file into your target host?

Comment: impdp system/**********@pdborcl dumpfile=**********.dmp schemas=ACSELE_BRHN,  ACSELEINT_BRHN, ACSELEGU_BRHN  logfile=imp_Backup27-10-2018-Pre_ProdWi.log

Comment: No, I mean the tool you used to transfer the file from source to target host?

Comment: using sqlplus tool

Comment: `O/S-Error: (OS 1117)` seems to indicate you have a problem with your storage device. I suggest you contact your DBA or sysadmin, and ask them to investigate.